# Material Design Components Site

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, material-components, android-components

Today I was Googling for "material design components" I ended up at this site:

https://material.io/components/

As I remember, I've never seen it before.

In the [Android section](https://material.io/components/android/) there are instruction to use the components and ok, it seems to be the well-known Android Design Support Library:

[image: Screenshot of dependencies]

But what intrigues me is that there are components there that are not in the design library, such as:

[Back Layer Layout](https://material.io/components/android/catalog/back-layer-layout/), [Material Card](https://material.io/components/android/catalog/material-card-view/) and [Material Button](https://material.io/components/android/catalog/material-button/).

The docs for these classes seems to be not ready yet and the links points to nowhere, like: [material button doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/button/MaterialButton.html).

There is something in the [github site](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/).

Sorry for ignorance, but what is the purpose of this site? Is it something future or something left behind?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Android Design Support Library was the precursor of the Material Design Components. As of the [Support Library 28.0.0-alpha1 release](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#28-0-0-alpha1), the Design Library now contains all of the new components introduced in the Material Design Components:

> We’ve introduced a new application theme, Theme.MaterialComponents, with new attributes and updated styles for components.
>
> We’ve added the following components:
>
> - BottomAppBar
> - Chip
> - ChipGroup
> - MaterialButton
> - MaterialCardView

While the `28.0.0-alpha1` release does contain all of the new classes, the documentation on developer.android.com does not yet contain the updates from the Design Library (keeping the docs effectively on what was publically available previously), but they are definitely there if you use that dependency.

Comment: Is there anything publicly written about where all this is going? For example, is the Design Support Library being discontinued, with Material Design Components getting its own artifact?

Comment: @CommonsWare - no, but expect more to come at I/O 2018.

Answer (score 2):

> The support libraries are now available through Google's Maven repository. We no longer support downloading the libraries through the SDK Manager, and that functionality will be removed soon..

as the [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup) says. And [this repository](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) and material library within it will be offical to use.

Latest dependencies to use material components is:

> com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1

[Getting started with Material Components for Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) will help you to setup your project.

Comment: Has it port to Xamarin? Thank you.

Comment: You should add a warning from the *Getting started page* (https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started) that says not use the **com.android.support** and **com.google.android.material** dependencies in an app at the same time